# Missing background color on StackExchange site's header link

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

When I click on `all sites` link on Stack Exchange the background color of this link does not get changed. For all other header links except `all sites` changes their background color on click. Following image will help to understand:

When clicked on `all sites`:

[image]

When clicked on `tagged questions`

[image]

Comment: what browser are you using? I see the same using IE8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, I introduced this while refactoring /sites view code.
It's fixed now. Thanks for the report.

Comment: At least you didn't make everything bold. (: